# So, is this the right way of storing passwords in a database?

Tags: php, database, hash, passwords

Would the following be a safe way of storing a user's password in a database?

When registering:

```
$salt=hash("sha512", rand());
$password=hash("sha512", $_POST["password"].$salt);

insert_values_into_db;
```

When logging in:

```
$given_password=$_POST["password"];

$salt=get_salt_from_db;
$correct_password=get_password_from_db;

if(hash("sha512", $given_password.$salt) === $correct_password){
    //Password is correct
}else{
    //Password is incorrect
}
```

Are there any blatantly obvious errors with this?

Comment: I'm not so caught up on which hash functions are the best to use these days but this logic seems sound.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me as a problem.

Comment: Although the best way would probably be using the password_hash() functions, or https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat for earlier versions of PHP

Answer (score 1):

Best solution: If you have PHP version 5.5 or above, use the [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. If not, check out the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library by ircmaxwell.

Answer (score 0):

All these hashes are optimized for speed and made to go easy on the processor. (MD5, SHA512, etc.) Because of this cracking them is just as easy.  I would either re-hash a couple of more times or just use the `crypt` method: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php.

Read more on password hashing in the documentation of PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Answer (score -1):

The most common way of storing passwords in a database people use is either

`md5` the password like : `md5($password)`

OR

`crypt($password)`

You could also add double md5 or double crypt for password to be really secure

Comment: md5, just say no. and double if you mean md5(md5($password)) actully decreases security